# How to apply the transform method to two variables in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I would like to create a new variable that is the dot product of two variables in a subgroup of my dataframe. I know that when I want to create a group-level variable, I can use the `transform` method. For example, in the dataset `auto` ([download](https://github.com/lucascr91/frontends/blob/master/auto.csv)) I can average the price of the brands as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("auto.csv")
#creates the brand variable
df['brand']=[k [0] for k in df.make.str.split ("")]

# average prices
df['price_mean']=df.groupby("brand")['price'].transform(np.mean)
df.head()
```

Result:

| make | price | mpg | rep78 | headroom | trunk | weight | length | turn | displacement | gear_ratio | foreign | brand | price_mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMC Concord | 4099 | 22 | 3 | 2.5 | 11 | 2930 | 186 | 40 | 121 | 3.58 | Domestic | AMC | 4215.67 |
| AMC Pacer | 4749 | 17 | 3 | 3 | 11 | 3350 | 173 | 40 | 258 | 2.53 | Domestic | AMC | 4215.67 |
| AMC Spirit | 3799 | 22 | nan | 3 | 12 | 2640 | 168 | 35 | 121 | 3.08 | Domestic | AMC | 4215.67 |
| Buick Century | 4816 | 20 | 3 | 4.5 | 16 | 3250 | 196 | 40 | 196 | 2.93 | Domestic | Buick | 6075.29 |
| Buick Electra | 7827 | 15 | 4 | 4 | 20 | 4080 | 222 | 43 | 350 | 2.41 | Domestic | Buick | 6075.29 |

I would like to do a similar operation using two variables.

The variable I want to create is called `result` and it is the result of the dot product of a dummy variable called `size` and the variable `price`. For one single brand it would look like this:

```py
df['size']=np.where(df.length> 200, 1.0)

tab=df[df.brand=='Olds']
tab['result']=np.dot(tab['price'], tab['size'])
tab
```

Result:

| make | price | mpg | rep78 | headroom | trunk | weight | length | turn | displacement | gear_ratio | foreign | brand | price_mean | size | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Olds 98 | 8814 | 21 | 4 | 4 | 20 | 4060 | 220 | 43 | 350 | 2.41 | Domestic | Olds | 6050.86 | 1 | 24075 |
| Olds Cutl Supr | 5172 | 19 | 3 | 2 | 16 | 3310 | 198 | 42 | 231 | 2.93 | Domestic | Olds | 6050.86 | 0 | 24075 |
| Olds Cutlass | 4733 | 19 | 3 | 4.5 | 16 | 3300 | 198 | 42 | 231 | 2.93 | Domestic | Olds | 6050.86 | 0 | 24075 |
| Olds Delta 88 | 4890 | 18 | 4 | 4 | 20 | 3690 | 218 | 42 | 231 | 2.73 | Domestic | Olds | 6050.86 | 1 | 24075 |
| Olds Omega | 4181 | 19 | 3 | 4.5 | 14 | 3370 | 200 | 43 | 231 | 3.08 | Domestic | Olds | 6050.86 | 0 | 24075 |
| Olds Starfire | 4195 | 24 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 2730 | 180 | 40 | 151 | 2.73 | Domestic | Olds | 6050.86 | 0 | 24075 |
| Olds Toronado | 10371 | 16 | 3 | 3.5 | 17 | 4030 | 206 | 43 | 350 | 2.41 | Domestic | Olds | 6050.86 | 1 | 24075 |

What I tried to do was:

```py
df.groupby('brand')[['price','size']].transform(lambda x,y: np.dot(x, y))
```

But it did not work. How can I do an operation on two variables using `transform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try piping a function that covers the transform part :

```
def np_dot(grp, columns):
    columns = [grp[column].transform(lambda x: x) for column in columns]
    return np.dot(*columns)


(
    df.assign(
        brand=df.make.str.split().str[0],
        price_mean=lambda df: df.groupby("brand").price.transform("mean"),
        size=np.where(df.length > 200, 1, 0),
    )
    .query('make.str.contains("Olds")', engine="python")
    .assign(result=lambda df: df.groupby("brand").pipe(np_dot, ["price", "size"]))
)
```

Comment: Should I apply this function in this way: `df['result']=np_dot(df.groupby('brand'), columns=['price','size'])`? This returns a unique value for all brands: 187704

Comment: If you run it with the code I shared you should get the 2475 for rows with `Old`, which is what your question is. Not sure about your other question. Could you clarify that in the main question area with a clear example. Thanks